# Необходимо получить id группы из ссылки https://vk.com/zabastovka_kna

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Дано:

```
https://vk.com/zabastovka_kna
```

Должно стать:

```
group_id = 159183588
```

Выглядит так, что `id` можно посмотреть в коде страницы, но возможно есть более стандартные средства?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого есть специальный метод: https://vk.com/dev/utils.resolveScreenName

Передаете туда zabastovka_kna, получаете тип объекта и id:

```
{
   "response": {
      "type": "group",
      "object_id": 159183588
   }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, на другом форуме посоветовали group.getBy